# Json parsing django rest framework

Tags: python, arrays, json, django, django-rest-framework

I want to parse incoming `POST` data in django views.py file

POST data:

```
{
"number" : "17386372",
"data" : ["banana","apple","grapes" ]  
}
```

Here is how I tried to read above incoming data with `request`

views.py

```
class Fruits(APIView):

def post(self, request, format=None):

   if request.method == "POST":

        number = request.data.get('number')
        fruits_data = json.loads(request.body)

        if number not in [None, '', ' ']:
            try:

                response = {"return": "OK","data":fruits_data['data']}
                return Response(response)
            except:
                return Response({"return": "NOT OK"})
        else:
            return Response({"return": "NOT OK"})

    else:
        return Response({"return": "NOT OK"})
```

ERROR:

```
You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream
```

Comment: Option 1: first ```json.loads```, then extract the ```'number'```. Option 2: ```from copy import deepcopy``` and ```my_copy = deepcopy(request)``` before wrecking the original object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

request.data and request.body are the two mechanisms, which reads the raw http request and construct data in a format, that is suitable to be used in python environment. Here the problem is that you are using both of them simultaneously. Thus, the inputstream of http connection is already read, by request.data call. Now request.body also tries to access the same stream, which doesn't contain now any data. Thus, it's throwing an error.

For you, I think following code will work :

```
fruits_data = json.loads(request.body)
number = fruits_data["number"]
```

Answer (score 4):

The Django json parser does this already for you:

```
from rest_framework import parsers

class Fruits(APIView):
    parser_classes = (parsers.JSONParser,)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        number = request.data['number']
        fruits = request.data['data']
```

If the `Content-Type` of your http request is already set properly to `application/json` you do not even need to specify the parser.