# Stripe parameter_invalid_integer

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios, stripe-payments

I am trying to setup PaymentIntents API from Stripe and the amount needed to be passed to the API is very confusing.

Stripe Docs:
*All API requests expect amounts to be provided in a currency’s smallest unit. For example, to charge 10 USD, provide an amount value of 1000 (i.e., 1000 cents). For zero-decimal currencies, still provide amounts as an integer but without multiplying by 100. For example, to charge ¥500, provide an amount value of 500.*

My frontend code to pass my backend the price:

```
const { data: clientSecret } = await axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/paymentIntent/", {
        amount: price * 100
      });
```

My backend:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def payment(request):
    try:
        amount = request.amount
        paymentIntent = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
            amount = amount,
            currency = "usd",
            # capture_method='manual',
            # metadata={'integration_check': 'accept_a_payment'},
        ) 

        data = paymentIntent.client_secret
```

If I put amount = 45 (random number for example), the payment intent works and everything goes through. If I put amount as the price from the request sent from my frontend,, it says this error message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "parameter_invalid_integer",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-invalid-integer",
    "message": "Invalid integer: {\"amount\":4300}",
    "param": "amount",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

In the above error the price of the item is $43 so I just pass in 43 x 100, isn't that correct? Maybe the amount isn't being passed as an integer but It looks fine to me.

Answer (score 2):

The error is saying you've passed a *value* of `{\"amount\":4300}` -- it looks like you're accidentally passing some object instead of the integer value.

eg: you're sending something like `amount={\"amount\":4300}` instead of the expected `amount=4300`.

You need to review how `amount` is being passed around and provided to the Payment Intent create call.

**Update (not a fix)**:
Try using a different variable name:

```
requestAmount = request.amount
paymentIntent = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
  amount = requestAmount,
  currency = "usd",
)
```

**Update 2**: Likely need to parse the json body:

```
data = json.loads(request.body)
paymentIntent = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
  amount = data.amount,
  currency = "usd",
)
```

Comment: How do I parse only the number in {\"amount\":4300} ?

Comment: I'm not sure why it's got that extra layer. You should log/print `request.amount` to diagnose and then extract the numeric value.

Comment: Actually this may be related to the way python handled variables. Can you try using a non-colliding name with the payment intent parameter?

Comment: If I try a non-colliding name and use request.amount it throws 400 Bad Request and doesn't show any logs on Stripe. It only shows the above Stripe log error when I pass request.body. Super weird

Comment: Wow I just did request.body[10:-1] to get the price and it worked lol

Comment: While that may work, it's a kludge that doesn't really address the real problem. In the snippet you posted you have `request.amount` -- is that not what you're doing right now? If you're sending `request.body` then the error seems perfectly logical. In your `axios.post` you're sending `{amount: 4300}` so using `amount=request.body` in your Stripe call would be expected to return the error we were discussing. You need to pull out the `amount` value from the `request.body`. Have you tried `request.body.amount`?

Comment: Yea when I tried request.body.amount it gave me the same 400 Bad Request error but it didn't show any logs on Stripe. The error log only appears on Stripe when I did request.body

Comment: You likely need to parse the json body and then access `amount` there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40447448/12474862

Answer (score -2):

check the result of price * 100
for example in javascript:

price=270.59

Logger.log(price*100) => 27058.999999999996